# How can I get a panel in Splunk to show the results of an external API call?

Tags: splunk

Specifically, I have an API that returns some JSON. What I want to do is have the user go on the dashboard, type the input (in this case an IP address) and have the results of the external API call(for example a number pulled from a field in the response) be displayed in the panel. Is this doable? If so how? Bonus points for doing it without needing access to the backend.

Answer (score -1):

ℹThis is not possible without the required access rights to upload JS files. What you're trying to do is a better use case for a custom command that enhances the result set.

⚠️ Allowing users to do this would leave your Splunk instance open to many security vulnerabilities.

With that in mind, if you can add JS files to a dashboard definition, then you could:

Write a javascript function that is executed on some user action (i.e. a button press). This function needs to:

1. do an HTTP call to fetch the data (i.e. via browser native `fetch` or [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios))
2. pick wanted data out of response / handle possible errors
3. set the result to be shown in some way in the dashboard.

For this, you can use simple html/js techniques and specifically refer to how it's being done in [Splunk Dashboard Examples](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1603/)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it seems that you can't write JS on the dashboards themselves, you need to upload te js file to the backend which I do not have access to.